# Recode values omitting NA's

Tags: r, missing-data, recode

I want to recode the values in a matrix in such a way that all values <=.2 become 2, <=.4 become 3 etc. However, there are missings in my data, which I do not want to change (keep them NA). Here you find a simplified version of my code. Using na.omit works perfectly for the first changes

```
try <- matrix(c(0.78,0.62,0.29,0.47,0.30,0.63,0.30,0.20,0.15,0.58,0.52,0.64,
     0.76,0.32,0.64,0.50,0.67,0.27, NA), nrow = 19)
try[na.omit(try <= .2)] <- 2 #Indeed changes .20 and .15 to 2 and leaves the NA as NA
```

However, when I  do the same for a higher category, the NA is also changed:

```
try[na.omit(try <= .8)] <- 5 #changes all other values including the NA to 5
```

Can someone explain to me what is the difference between the two and why the second one also changes the NA-value while the first one does not? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: You can just do `try[try <= .8] <- 5`.  The NA will remain as such.   or you can have a condition `try[try <=.8 & !is.na(try)] <- 5`

Comment: Thanks, I expected it too be pretty easy. I didn't try because `try[try <= .8]`  did include the NA, but good to know that in changing the values this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
try[try <= .8] <- 5
```

The `NA` values will remain as `NA`

Or create a logical condition to exclude the `NA` values

```
try[try <=.8 & !is.na(try)] <- 5
```